# SQLite soundex string length

Tags: sqlite, soundex

Does soundex function in sqlite has limitation on string length?
As I found that the result of

```
SELECT soundex('Schneider Thomson'), soundex('Schneider Rene'), soundex('Schneider')
```

Are all the same value which equal S536, However the result of :

```
SELECT soundex('Schn Thomson'), soundex('Schn Rene'), soundex('Schn');
```

Is different for each string and the values is

```
soundex('Schn Thomson') = S535 
soundex('Schn Rene')    = S565
soundex('Schn')         = S500
```

Please can any one explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Soundex algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) is desgined to work on single words.
(To simplify, it encodes the first letter and the first three following consonants.)

Answer (score 1):

To provide a little more clarification to CL's answer, the encoding uses the first letter and then encodes the following consonants (with the exception of H,W,Y) until 3 digits have been generated. Mississippi is a word that illustrates this well. MISSISSIPPI has a SOUNDEX of M210.

1. M is the first letter followed by the first consonant S. S is then repeated and ignored by SOUNDEX encoding.
2. The next consonant is P and it is not followed by another valid letter (just a repeated p and an i).
3. Thus a zero is the final digit.

Hopefully that provides a little more clarification on how SOUNDEX encodes words. For a little more information, this article from [Genealogy.com](http://www.genealogy.com/articles/research/00000060.html) explains how to use `SOUNDEX` when researching names. This would explain why supercell and supercalifragilisticexpialidocious have the same SOUNDEX, S162.

Comment: A more common example with SOUNDEX and names - Alison and Alexander both have values A425 (ALSN = ALXN)